# sum of column with group by and show it in listed table

Tags: mysql, sum

I want to show the report of sales item.

**product table**

```
id,name,information,stock,MRP
```

**sales table**

```
id,quantity,sales_price,product_id,sold_quantity.
```

now I want to show all the detail havng the sold_quantity of sum of all quantity.

below query run but individually.I want to show both at 1 time like

[image]

```
SELECT product_id,sum(quantity) as quantity FROM sales GROUP BY product_id;
select product.name,product.information,sales.cost_price,sales.quantity from sales inner join product on sales.product_id=product.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to do this, try this;)

```
select product.name, product.information, sales.cost_price, sales.quantity, t.quantity as sold_quantity
from sales
inner join product on sales.product_id=product.id
left join (
    select product_id, sum(quantity) as quantity
    from sales
    group by product_id
) t on t.product_id = product.id
```